# "Error establishing a database connection" after days of site running

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

I am running Wordpress on AWS (Ubuntu). and have a very weird issue, every few days the database crashes and I am getting the "Error establishing a database connection" message. When I restart it with

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Everything works fine, until the next time it happens several days later.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the log file of MySQL. What does it say around a crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using micro instance? If so, then you are probably running out of memory.
The workaround is to create a swap as a file.
This are the steps to do that:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo chown root:root /swapfile
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Now edit /etc/fstab file, so that when you restart the system, swap can be mounted automaticaly.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

And add this in the file:

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

To get better performance from swap file in AWS you need to do this too:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: is there a way to track down the memory usage before mysql crashed?

BTW, running free -m after doing your changes gives this:
ubuntu@ip-XX-XX-XX-XXX:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1652       1634         18          0         83        794
-/+ buffers/cache:        756        896
Swap:          511          0        511

Comment: You can check system logs (dmesg), and look for oom-killer.
By that free -m output, you are at the edge of a crash. Monitor the system next few days, and see what happends. I would recommend that you install some monitoring tool like nagios.